# Swift: Explain grammar syntax for NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I'm a new comer to iOS World. When I see a method for downloading file. I see this code:

```
        // create url
        let imageURL = NSURL(string: Constants.CatURL)!

        // create task
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(imageURL) {
            (data, response, error) in print("task finished")
        }
```

I don't really understand part:

```
 {
        (data, response, error) in print("task finished")
    }
```

Where `data` `response` `error` objects come from? And which type are they? I'm familiar with some languages such Java, C# and above structure very strange: after a method call is a `{}` codeblock. I just see that in iOS there are two methods that very different from above:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url: NSURL)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url: NSURL, completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void)
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff in `{ ... }` is an anonymous function body. The stuff in `(...) in` are the names of the parameters passed to the function.

The part of your question about "which type are they?" is a really good question. The answer is that Swift knows about this declaration, which you cited:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url: NSURL, completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void)
```

So Swift already knows the types of the three parameters, and thus the types can optionally be omitted (and here they have in fact been omitted).

You may also be confused by the omission of the label `completionHandler:`. This is legal because this function is the *last* parameter. In that case, it is legal to drop the label and put the anonymous function body outside the function call parentheses (known as "trailing syntax").

Thus, the code you cited *is* in fact a legal form for implementing `dataTaskWithURL(_:completionHandler:)`.

Comment: More explanation of anonymous function declaration syntax here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions

Comment: If return is `Void`. we can omit part `->()`, right?

Comment: Yes, and in that case we can also omit the parentheses and write `param, param, param in`. Again, please see the link I gave you. It's all there, waiting for you to read it. So in this example, they could have written that, but they didn't.

Comment: thanks. I have read to that part and understand :D My last question for this question is: Is this a very normal way for writing swift code? Do you prefer writing concise code like this, or write full code (full code in this situation means: still use anonymous function but have parameter type, return type, method label). thanks :)

Comment: It depends! Often, I use all the omissions I'm allowed. But let's go back to your original question. It surely might be more legible to write `(data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in`, because now we've answered our own question, namely what _types_ these things are. So I very often do that.